# React Firebase read element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get the value stored in 'Nombre', but it doesn't work at all, am I doing something wrong?

```
class Appp extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = { name: 'hey' }
}
componentDidMount() {
    const nameRef = firebase.database().ref().child('Anonimos').child('wx3czBh22dMQUTNDwD9l').child('Nombre')
    nameRef.on('value', snapshot => {
        this.setState({
            name: snapshot.val()
        })
    })
}

render() {
    return <h1>{this.state.name}</h1>
}
}
```

[image: Firebase]

Comment: what are you getting now? Also add your database to the question

Comment: Done. Right now I keep getting 'hey', but I wanna get 'Alejandro'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code uses the API for the Firebase Realtime Database. But the screenshot shows data in Cloud Firestore. While both databases are part of Firebase, they are completely separate and the API for one can't access the data in the other.

To access the data in Cloud Firestore, follow the documentation for **that** database: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart

Something like:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const nameRef = firebase.firestore().collection('Anonimos').doc('wx3czBh22dMQUTNDwD9l')
    nameRef.onSnapshot(doc => {
        this.setState({
            name: doc.data().Nombre
        })
    })
}
```

Aside from the new syntax, the biggest change here is that this code reads the entire document, instead of just the `Nombre` field, and then sets just the name in the state. So while the end result is the same, this loads more data than your Realtime Database example would, since that API allow the loading of any node, while Cloud Firestore always loads complete documents.

Comment: You are absolutely right, that worked. Thank you very much!